# Commit message amend using rebasing on feature branch and then merging into master

Tags: git, github, commit, rebase, pull-request

I have an old commit which was made on one old branch, say "old_branch_1". This commit was merged into my "master" branch via a Pull Request. Now I need to amend the message of that commit. So I followed steps as below:

1. Created a new branch from "master", say "new_branch_1".
2. Did checkout new_branch_1.
3. used git rebase -i HEAD~50
   And then amended the required commit message.
4. Once, rebase was completed. I was a 100 commits ahead of remote and around 120 commits behind of remote.
5. Did git pull (and resolved the conflicts).
   Now I was 200 odd commits ahead.
6. Did git push.
7. Now, I have raised a PR to my master branch.

What I am not sure about is, whether post merging of PR, will it replace the old commit with new message or will it add this new commit to the top of master branch history.

I really need to get rid of old commit message from the history. since the old message is causing issues when merging my code into production branches.

Comment: You're dangerously close to https://twitter.com/henryhoffman/status/694184106440200192 by the sound of it. When you change a commit message, you create a new commit, and therefore create new version of all of the subsequent commits. This won't change any existing commits, it will just add more commits and make your history harder to understand.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I agree with you. But, still wondering. There has to be a way of achieving this?

Comment: Not, as noted below, without a force push that might cause problems with collaborators. Maybe you should look for fixes elsewhere (like find out why exactly the message alone is enough to cause what is presumably otherwise working code to not get merged).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The only way to get rid of the comment is to rebase and then force push.  That will most likely cause a lot of headaches if you're part of a team that has various topic branches currently in development.

A rebase changes the commit IDs of every affected commit.  After your rebase, you had the same number of commits as `master` at the time you branched off of it, but the most recent 50 had different commit ids.  At that point you should have been 50 commits ahead and 50 behind `master`.  Not sure how you wound up being 100 commits ahead.  The additional "commits behind" could have occurred if other code had been merged into `master` between your checkout and the completion of your rebase.

When you merged `master` back into your branch, you brought back all 50 of those commits your rebase modified, including the commit messages.  Your PR will not overwrite anything in the existing remote, but only add 50 more commits that are identical to the corresponding commits in your remote, with the exception that one of your new commits has a different comment message.

Comment: hey, sorry for the numbers in the question. I don't remember the exact numbers, but I am sure no other code was commited while I was checking out and rebasing. Let's just assume, I was 50 ahead and 50 behind from remote branch. Now, at this point, If I force push into remote, will it remove the old commit? And also, mind you, I am force pushing into the remote feature branch and not master. I need to raise a PR from this remote feature branch to remote master as well later.

Comment: You need to force push into the branch whose commits you want to overwrite.  I'd be surprised if any system would allow such a thing to happen via a PR.